# Jquery getJSON is not working within MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to do a getJSON but for some reason it is silently failing.

Here is the code:

```
   $("#distanceMiles").change(function () {

                        $("#distanceMiles option:selected").each(function () {

                             var manufacturerId = <%= Model.Manufacturer.Id%>;

                             var postcodeEntered = $("#enterPostCode").val();

                             var milesEntered = $(this).val();


                               if (postcodeEntered != null && milesEntered != null) {

                                   var fqdn = "<%: Model.FullyQualifiedDomainName %>";

                                   var theUrl ="http://localhost:7310/Widgets/GetPostcodes/" + manufacturerId + "/" + postcodeEntered + "/" + milesEntered;
                                   alert(theUrl);

                                   // 3. Get the response back from the Controller (which will arrive in the form of a callback
                                   $.getJSON(theUrl + "?callback=?", { }, callback);
                                   alert("here");
                                   // 4. This callback will then decide ? Do I call myself and ask again, OR do i just return (unwind the stack) 
                                   // This will get called AFTER the json has finished i.e. my controller returns

                                   function callback(data1) {

                                       // This will be filled in once i am receiving data back...

                                       alert(data1);


                                   }
                               }

                        });
                    });
```

I am using MVC3 and have checked the following:
That the routing is set up correctly in the glabal.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("GetPostcodes", "Widgets/GetPostcodes/{manufacturerId}/{postcodeEntered}/{milesEntered}/{callback}", new { controller = "Widgets", action = "GetPostcodes", manufacturerId = 0, postcodeEntered = "", milesEntered = 0, callback = "" });
```

That the parameters all have values:

```
 alert(theUrl);
```

If I put the Url in the address bar it hits my WidgetController as expected and returns so i  know the url is valid.

Here is the Widget controller code:

```
 [JsonpFilter]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult GetPostcodes(int manufacturerId, string postcodeEntered, int milesEntered, String callback)
        {
            //get long and lat for entered postcode
            var postcodeData = _postcodeRepository.GetPostcodeFromCode(postcodeEntered);

            var postLong = postcodeData.Longitude;

            var postLat = postcodeData.Latitude;

            //Using the manufacturerofflineretailers get all the stores which has the postcodes
            var listRetailers =
                _manufacturerOfflineRetailerRepository.GetManufacturerOfflineRetailerForManufacturer(manufacturerId);


            //we need to add a list of stores to display
            var anonymous2 = new List<StoreJson>(); // a list of my anonymous type without the relationships

            //then we want to loop through every postcode using calcDistance with  entered postcode long and lat and each store long and lat and only add if less than milesentered.
            foreach (var retailer in listRetailers)
            {
                var listStores = _storeRepository.GetAllStoresForRetailer(retailer.RetailerId);

                foreach (var store in listStores)
                {


                    //get lat long using store postcodeid
                    var storeData = _postcodeRepository.GetPostcode(store.PostcodeId);

                    var retailerData = _retailerRepository.GetRetailer(store.RetailerId);

                    var storeName = retailerData.Description;

                    var address1 = store.Address1;

                    var townCity = store.TownCity;

                    var postcode = store.Postcode;

                    var telephone = store.Telephone;

                    var fax = store.Fax;

                    var storeLong = storeData.Longitude;
                    var storeLat = storeData.Latitude;
                    var calcDistance = GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(postLong, postLat, storeLong, storeLat);

                    // Create the reply for the client to consume
                    var storeJson = new StoreJson
                                        {
                                            StoreName = storeName,
                                            Address1 = address1,
                                            TownCity = townCity,
                                            Postcode = postcode,
                                            Telephone = telephone,
                                            Fax = fax,
                                            Distance = calcDistance
                                        };

                    //we only want to add this if the calcDistance is less than milesEntered
                    if (calcDistance <= milesEntered)
                    {
                        anonymous2.Add(storeJson);
                    }
                }

            }

            return Json(anonymous2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

I have also had a look in fiddler but it doesn't try to do anything so no errors occur but it does not get to my next alert:

```
 $.getJSON(theUrl + "?callback=?", { }, callback);
                                   alert("here");
```

Any help appreciated - not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok not sure why getJSON doesn t work and would still like some insight if anyone has any but to make my code work i used ajax as follows:

```
                           var theUrl ="/Widgets/GetPostcodes/" + manufacturerId + "/" + postcodeEntered + "/" + milesEntered;


                             $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: theUrl,
                                data: { 'manufacturerId': manufacturerId, 'postcodeEntered': postcodeEntered, 'milesEntered': milesEntered },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {

                                    alert(data);
                                }
               });
```

and changed the controller to :

```
[JsonpFilter]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult GetPostcodes(int manufacturerId, string postcodeEntered, int milesEntered, String callback)
        {
```

Which does what I needed it to do. Hope this may help others